Node can not be reached with ansible after changes of groups in inventory
I had an inventory.yaml like that:
all:
  children:
    windows:
      children:
        jenkins:
          children:
            old:
              host1.com:
              host2.com:

both nodes can be reached.
If I do move node to another group like that:
all:
  children:
    windows:
      children:
        jenkins:
          children:
            old:
              host1.com:
            new:
              host2.com:

then host2.com can be reached as well.
But if I create another group like that:
all:
  children:
    windows:
      children:
        jenkins:
          children:
            old:
              host1.com:
    maintenance:
      host2.com:

then host2.com can not be reached with error:
"msg": "timed out waiting for ping module test: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /nfs/location/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: /nfs/location/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: /nfs/location/.ssh/config line 33: Applying options for *.location.com\r\ndebug1: /nfs/location/.ssh/config line 40: Applying options for *.*\r\ndebug1: /nfs/location/.ssh/config line 46: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 23: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 67: Applying options for *location.com\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 72: Applying options for *.*.*\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 77: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/nfs/location/.ansible/cp/eeeeeeeeee\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"host2.com\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to host2.com [10.40.123.123] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 10.40.123.123 port 22: Connection refused\r\nssh: connect to host host2.com port 22: Connection refused"


Check your group vars. Chances are you define connection vars in group windows or one of its children
